# What location CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in JPA get in Java using database postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime, jpa, datetime-format

I using jpa and using jpa custom query excute method. I using TypedQuery and Entity manage excute when i write query. My Jpa excute look like :

```
String query = "select s from Student s where (b.beginDate + b.beginTime) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP";
```

But when i excute it, it wrong when i select. It differs up to 2 hours
I have 2 question:

1. When i excute it, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP get database time, server
   containing database or server running java machine. Because I have 2
   servers. A server contains a database with a Paris time zone and a
   server running spring with a JDK containing a Japan time zone.
2. When I create it, I want format **`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:Mm:SS'`**

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Hello Tbtrungdn, can you specify what represents 'b.' in your SELECT ? Are you sure that your SELECT is working ? "SELECT s" or "SELECT *" ? Have you defined a column named 's' ? If Your SELECT is false, can you correct it and split on multiple line so SELECT is more readble ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing todo with JPA !

In Postgresql documentation it is written

> The PostgreSQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() function returns the current date
>   and time with time zone, which is the time when the transaction
>   starts.

The TimeStamp returned is always a data and time WITH TIME ZONE.

In your SELECT the comparison will work if you have previously saved a time in same format.

If you have a field BEGIN_DATE_TIME with correct format, no problem.

You have certainly a problem because (b.BEGINDATE + b.BEGINTIME) will not produce a date and time with time zone value !

Can you give us more information about these 2 fields ?